# How do I access this value in this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I did a `json_decode` and when I `var_dump` the results variable I get this below.

I have bold the value I am trying to extract but I simply cannot figure out the levels of the associative array to grab that value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
array(2) {
    ["data"]=> array(16) {
        ["expiration_schedule"]=> array(0) { }
        ["last_name"]=> string(11) "johnsonwill"
        ["loyalty_tier_name"]=> string(6) "Silver"
        ["uid"]=> string(20) "**kylesmp1f@yahoo.com**"
        ["dob"]=> string(10) "10/22/1981"
        ["referrer_email"]=> string(0) ""
        ["loyalty_tier_id"]=> string(10) "zrl_silver"
        ["first_name"]=> string(4) "Kyle"
        ["loyalty_enroll_time"]=> string(10) "02/06/2018"
        ["available_points"]=> int(50)
        ["referral_code"]=> string(8) "FJWKAWFHWA"
        ["redeemed_points"]=> int(0)
        ["awarded_points"]=> int(50)
        ["has_opted_out"]=> bool(false)
        ["user_email"]=> string(20) "kylesmp1f@yahoo.com"
        ["pending_points"]=> int(0) 
    }
    ["success"]=> bool(true) 
}
```

Comment: Can you please re-format your code? It's messing up. You can read more about formatting here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: thank you very much, I will be sure to format in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a multidimensional array. If your array name is $test[], you would access that value in this way:

```
echo $test["data"]["uid"];
```

See the full implementation here:

```
$data = array(
    "expiration_schedule" => array(),
    "last_name" => "johnsonwill",
    "loyalty_tier_name" => "Silver",
    "uid" => "kylesmp1f@yahoo.com",
    "dob" => "10/22/1981" ,
    "referrer_email" => "",
    "loyalty_tier_id" => "zrl_silver",
    "first_name" => "Kyle" ,
    "loyalty_enroll_time" => "02/06/2018" ,
    "available_points" => 50,
    "referral_code" => "FJWKAWFHWA" ,
    "redeemed_points" => 0,
    "awarded_points" => 50,
    "has_opted_out" => false,
    "user_email" => "kylesmp1f@yahoo.com" ,
    "pending_points" => 0
);
$success = true;

$test = array("data" => $data, "success" => $success);

echo $test["data"]["uid"];
```

Comment: thank you very much, for some reason the name data was throwing me off. I had assumed that was some sort of php keyword and not the name of the first dimension!